# Save result of stored procedure to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a stored procedure like the one shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBusinessUnitSysNameAndGroupNames] 
    @ModelAfter varchar(100),
    @BusinessUnitSystemName varchar(100) OUT,
    @GroupsName varchar(4000) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    if (@ModelAfter = 'Corporate') 
    BEGIN
        SET @GroupsName = 'Admins'
        SET @BusinessUnitSystemName = 'AcmeOutdoors'
    END 
    else if (@ModelAfter = 'Retailers')
    BEGIN
        SET @GroupsName = 'Sellers'
        SET @BusinessUnitSystemName = 'AcmeShoppers'
    END
END
```

When I run from the SQL Studio command line:

```
EXEC [dbo].[GetBusinessUnitSysNameAndGroupNames] '~ModelAfter~', 'acmeoutdoors', 'admins'
```

I just get a result in the message panel like `Command(s) completed successfully.` But what I would like to see the actual result, not just a success message. Something like shown below(which doesn't work, just my idea).

```
DECLARE @Result varchar(max)
SET @Result = EXEC [dbo].[GetBusinessUnitSysNameAndGroupNames] '~ModelAfter~', 'acmeoutdoors', 'admins'
PRINT @Result
```

Comment: You are passing constant strings where `OUT` parameters are expected.  Someone is very confused.

Comment: And the return value from a stored procedure is always an int. It is NOT intended to be used to pass data, it is an indication of the status of the execution of the procedure.

Comment: Although you have not actually fallen into the trap of using `RETURN` when you should use `OUTPUT`, but the following article is still a worthwhile read: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT or RETURN instead of OUTPUT](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't write the SP, just trying to debug some code and understand what it's returning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ### Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters
>
> If you specify the OUTPUT keyword for a parameter in the procedure
> definition, the stored procedure can return the current value of the
> parameter to the calling program when the stored procedure exits. To
> save the value of the parameter in a variable that can be used in the
> calling program, the calling program must use the OUTPUT keyword when
> executing the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @Result1 varchar(max), @Result2, varchar(max)
EXEC [dbo].[GetBusinessUnitSysNameAndGroupNames] 'Corporate', @Result1 OUT, @Result2 OUT

PRINT @Result1
PRINT @Result2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!